# Does spring have a shutdown process to put cleanup code?

Tags: java, spring

When my spring web app shuts down, is there an event I can wireup to somehow that I can perform some cleanup code to empty out some pools etc.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You Could use the following

1. destroy-method <del>as @amir75 recommends</del>
2. [@PreDestroy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) annotation
3. Implement [DisposableBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean.html) and override destroy method.

All the deatails about these can be found at [Disposable Callbacks](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-disposablebean).

Answer (score 7):

Spring beans have a 'destroy-method' attribute, which will be invoked when you 'close' your context.

```
<bean id="bean1" 
    destroy-method="stop"
    class="com.example.Bean" />
```

In order to close it, you'd call the close() method:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#close%28%29

(or just shut down the container if appropriate)

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 7):

Based on the JSR-250 specification the best practice to use in modern spring application is the `@PreDestroy` annotation since using this approach will decouple your beans from Spring.

Answer (score 5):

The non-Spring way to handle this is to write a class that implements [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and do your cleanup in its `contextDestroyed` method.  You'd add your class as a context listener in web.xml.

Comment: The trouble with this approach is that Spring is probably doing the same thing, and it is not obvious whether your custom servlet context listener will run before ... or after the Spring one.  This could make life awkward.

Comment: I don't know why I answered a Spring questions with "the non-Spring way" but that was 9 years ago when I was new to Spring.  Now that I have 9 more years of experience with Spring I say the accepted answer is correct, `@PreDestroy` is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Spring Boot logback example project, you should close the context to clean up the logging system: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/10402a651f1ee51704b58985c7ef33619df2c110

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleLogbackApplication.class, args).close();
    }
```

Comment: Dose this close all connections opened to datasource?

Comment: I don't think that's what this example says. This example shows a minimal Spring application that is started, logs a couple of messages (from a method annotated with @PostConstruct) and is then immediately closed. The question is about reacting to the application context closing and doing some cleanup (and @PreDestroy is probably the best way to do that, as suggested in other answers)