# Spring Boot shutdown hook

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I register/add a custom shutdown routine that shall fire when my Spring Boot application shuts down?

Scenario: I deploy my Spring Boot application to a Jetty servlet container (i.e., no embedded Jetty). My application uses Logback for logging, and I want to change logging levels during runtime using Logback's MBean JMX configurator. [Its documentation states that to avoid memory leaks, on shutdown a specific LoggerContext shutdown method has to be called](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/jmxConfig.html#leak).

What are good ways to listen on Spring Boot shutdown events?

I have tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext cac = SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);

    cac.addApplicationListener(new ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
            logger.info("Do something");
        }
    });
}
```

but this registered listener does not get called when the application shuts down.

Comment: You are registering the listener after the context is created, basically rendering it useless. If you want it to participate you need to register it as a bean in your application context like any other bean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does spring have a shutdown process to put cleanup code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585350/does-spring-have-a-shutdown-process-to-put-cleanup-code)

Answer (score 43):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.application-exit

> Each SpringApplication will register a shutdown hook with the JVM to ensure that the ApplicationContext is closed gracefully on exit. All the standard Spring lifecycle callbacks (such as the DisposableBean interface, or the @PreDestroy annotation) can be used.
>
> In addition, beans may implement the org.springframework.boot.ExitCodeGenerator interface if they wish to return a specific exit code when the application ends.

Comment: I have updated my question to show my current unsuccessful effort

Comment: Updated link https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-exit

Comment: Exact tab link : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.spring-application.application-exit

Answer (score 37):

have you tried this as mentioned by @cfrick ?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class SpringBootShutdownHookApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootShutdownHookApplication.class, args);
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void onExit() {
    log.info("###STOPing###");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      log.error("", e);;
    }
    log.info("###STOP FROM THE LIFECYCLE###");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Your listener is registered too late (that line will never be reached until the context has already closed). It should suffice to make it a `@Bean`.

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar use case, where I have to hold the server's shutdown process for some minutes, I have used the same approach mentioned in the question, the only change is instead of adding the listener after booting the service, I have added the listener (`ContextClosedEvent`) before running the application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.addListeners((ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>) event -> {
            log.info("Shutdown process initiated...");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.error("Exception is thrown during the ContextClosedEvent", e);
            }
            log.info("Graceful Shutdown is processed successfully");
        });
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: you must restore interrupted flag on catch.

Answer (score 4):

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletListenerRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Bean
    ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> myServletListener() {
        ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> srb =
                new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>();
        srb.setListener(new ExampleServletContextListener());
        return srb;
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class ExampleServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(
        ServletContextEvent sce) {
    // Context Initialised
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(
        ServletContextEvent sce) {
       // Here - what you want to do that context shutdown    
   }
}
```