# How to gracefuly shutdown a Spring Boot application by start-stop-daemon

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, start-stop-daemon

We have a multithreaded Spring Boot Application, which runs on Linux machine as a daemon. When I try to stop the application by start-stop-daemon like this

```
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
```

The SIGTERM signal is sent and application immetiately ends. However I want the application to wait, until every thread finishes it's work.

Is there any way, how to manage what happens, when SIGTERM signal is received?

Comment: If you're interested in shutting down the embedded servlet container gracefully, please see [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4657).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does spring have a shutdown process to put cleanup code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585350/does-spring-have-a-shutdown-process-to-put-cleanup-code)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Spring Boot app registers a shutdown hook with the JVM to ensure that the `ApplicationContext` is closed gracefully on exit. Create bean (or beans) that implements `DisposableBean` or has method with `@PreDestroy` annotation. This bean will be invoked on app shutdown.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-exit

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However this does not solve my problem, because I somehow need to intercept the SIGTERM signal and wait until application finishes it's work. This allows me to do some cleanup, but if I understand it correctly, this does not allow me to prevent termination of currently running method.

Comment: @Michal You're right, it doesn't allow you to prevent termination. But it allows to implement threads stopping logic and wait until threads finish. The JVM won't be terminated if shutdown hook works.

Comment: It should be noted, though, that the use of `DisposableBean` is not recommended by Spring, '... because it unnecessarily couples the code to Spring.' [https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-disposablebean] Better use `@PreDestroy` instead.

Answer (score 5):

sample as mentioned by @Evgeny

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class SpringBootShutdownHookApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootShutdownHookApplication.class, args);
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void onExit() {
    log.info("###STOPing###");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      log.error("", e);;
    }
    log.info("###STOP FROM THE LIFECYCLE###");
  }
}
```