# How to graceful shutdown tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, graceful-shutdown

I want Tomcat graceful shut down.

- with spring boot 2.2.2 version
- with external tomcat 9.x (not embedded tomcat)

---

I tried as below.

- kill -TERM $(tomcat PID)
- Apply spring actuator -> call `localhost:8080/actuactor/shutdown`
- application.yml `server:shutdown:graceful` -> not working because my spring boot version is 2.2.2

None of the above three methods were gracefully shutdown. (All terminated immediately.)

**How do I shutdown tomcat gracefully?**

Comment: You can’t shutdown a container from the application that is running inside of it. There are some workarounds using command line commands but none of these will be graceful.

Comment: Does any of these answer your question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585350/does-spring-have-a-shutdown-process-to-put-cleanup-code

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691355/how-to-gracefuly-shutdown-a-spring-boot-application-by-start-stop-daemon

Comment: If the external tomcat is installed as service, you should be able to stop it gracefully by invoking the stop method. (`service tomcat stop`, `net stop tomcat`, ...)

Comment: How can you tell that Tomcat terminated abruptly? Don't you have a `Stopping service [Catalina]` sequence in the logs?